# deploy new version of azure container app

Tags: azure-cli, azure-container-apps

I've followed [this guide to deploy my custom image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/get-started-existing-container-image) but now I'm stuck on how do I deploy `vNext` of my container image?

Skimming [this YouTube video,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-HC2lGKpLg) it seems [revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/revisions) are the way but how using the Azure CLI?

There's also an interesting concepts page on [application lifecycle management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/application-lifecycle-management) but no guides/tutorials on this topic of revisions, only [the api guide pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/revision?view=azure-cli-latest).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need to [update the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/revisions-manage?tabs=bash#update) for a new image.  This action will create a new revision behind the scenes.

```
az containerapp update `
  --name <APPLICATION_NAME> `
  --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> `
  --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/containerapps-helloworld
```

2. Depending on your [activeRevisionsMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/revisions-manage?tabs=bash#set-active-revision-mode) property:
   a. if single then revision should automatically get activates.
   b. if mulitple then [activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/revisions-manage?tabs=bash#activate) and configure [traffic-splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/revisions-manage?tabs=bash#traffic-splitting)

Comment: I don't directly create the new revision if using [update app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/revisions-manage?tabs=bash#update), right?  it does that for me, right?

Comment: Correct, revision is created implicitly.

Comment: What must be done with the old revisions? Purge them after each update?

Comment: @jpruiz114, you can set a limit on old revisions to maintain and the service will purge automatically.

Answer (score 0):

create a [revision copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/revision?view=azure-cli-latest#az-containerapp-revision-copy) pointing to the new image:

```
$RESOURCE_GROUP="my-resource-group"
$CONTAINER_APP_NAME="my-image"
$NEW_IMAGE="myregistry.azurecr.io/smile:vNext"

az containerapp revision copy --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP `
   --name $CONTAINER_APP_NAME `
   --image $NEW_IMAGE
```